# C# MongoDB.Driver .NET 5 slow query times

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have moved to a new C# .NET Core 5 application and have noticed some significant performance differences with the MongoDB.Driver(2.12.3) vs alternatives like PyMongo(Python) or KMongo(Kotlin). I am not a .NET or Mongo expert however I have ruled out what I would imagine to be the obvious. The wellUid has an index and I have validated that the query is only taking sub 10 milliseconds to complete using explain (via MongoCompass). I have tried removing serialization to C# class and used BsonDocument as the serialization class which resulted in poorer performance. I think I have ruled out everythign that would point to a server or query issue and this looks more like something in the environment / serialization.

### **.NET 5 (C#)**

Please note that I have tried Find as well along with modifying the batching size using query options. Nothing has cut any significant time off the request.

```
    [Fact(DisplayName = "Time fetching KPI indeicators")]
    public void TestPerformance()
    {
        mongoClientSettings.ClusterConfigurator = cb => {
            cb.Subscribe<CommandStartedEvent>(e => {
                _testOutputHelper.WriteLine($"{e.CommandName} - {e.Command.ToJson()}");
            });
        };
        
        var mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoClientSettings);
        var drilling = mongoClient.GetDatabase("drilling");
        var kpiOneMin = drilling.GetCollection<KPI>("kpiOneMin");
        
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var kpis = kpiOneMin.Aggregate().Match(x => x.WellId == "ABC").ToList();
            watch.Stop();
            _testOutputHelper.WriteLine($"Iteration: {i+1}, Count: {kpis.Count}, Time Millis: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");   
        }
    }
```

***Output***

I have ran this many times and the results stay pretty much in the same range between 6-7 seconds.

```
Iteration: 1, Count: 21152, Time Millis: 7064
Iteration: 2, Count: 21152, Time Millis: 6381
Iteration: 3, Count: 21152, Time Millis: 6425
```

### **Python**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = MongoClient(uri)
    pipeline = [{"$match": {"wellUid": "ABC"}} ]
                
    for i in range(3):
        v = client.drilling.kpiOneMin.aggregate(pipeline)
        start_time = time.time()
        list(v)
        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

***Output***

```
--- 4.739964246749878 seconds ---
--- 3.357880115509033 seconds ---
--- 3.3460099697113037 seconds ---
```

The result is 49%, 90% 92% faster than .NET 5 with MongoDriver.

### **Kotlin**

This is the kotlin example which from all accounts is exactly the same however performance is 40-80% faster based on the deltas in times. I tried Kotlin because I wanted to rule out the speed of python serialization to dictionaries.

```
val database = client.getDatabase("drilling")
val col = database.getCollectionOfName<KPI>("kpiOneMin")

repeat(3) { iteration ->
    var kpiCount: Int = 0;
    val timeInMillis = measureTimeMillis {
        val kpis = col.aggregate<KPI>(match(KPI::wellUid eq "ABC")).toList()
        kpiCount = kpis.size
    }
    println("Iteration: ${iteration + 1}, KPI Count: $kpiCount,  Time Millis: $timeInMillis")
}
```

***Output***

```
Iteration: 1, KPI Count: 21152,  Time Millis: 5515
Iteration: 2, KPI Count: 21152,  Time Millis: 3484
Iteration: 3, KPI Count: 21152,  Time Millis: 3501
```

The result is 28%, 83% and 83% faster than .NET 5 with MongoDriver.

Comment: Just curious as to whether this performance difference really matters in your use case. One language implementation being twice as fast as another would probably not matter under most circumstances. Are you routinely doing queries which take seconds?

Comment: Great question. We are working in a larger application and we need to provide timeseries data as quickly as possible. The simple 2 week request is really only for one entity there will be multiples in the future and a 50+% decrease in load times will be huge for someone analyzing data.

Comment: My expertise is definitely in wide column datastores (Cassandra, HBase, DynamoDB) rather than document databases so there may be something we are missing with IDs etc.

Comment: first try doing `drilling.GetCollection<object>("kpiOneMin");` so that the driver doesn't have to map data to `KPI` instances. see that makes any difference. if that doesn't change anything, try using the await/async pattern instead of `.ToList()` because the driver is doing sync-over-async anti-pattern to maintain backwards compatibility under the hood.

Comment: You should try running this on Benchmark.Net or a Console Application. Not sure what's the cost of WriteLine with TestOutputHelper, plus you are subscribing to a CommandStart event. Suggestion would be isolating the print statements outside the Stopwatch loop.